# Validation Rule to make picklist field mandatory based on picklist value selected?

Tags: validation

I have a Primary Department picklist that controls a Division picklist. I need the Division field to become mandatory if the Primary department picklist equals "Medicine", "Surgery", or "Pediatrics".

This is my validation rule so far:

```
and(
if(ISPICKVAL(PrimaryDepartment__c, "Medicine"),
ISPICKVAL(Division__c, ""),
if(ISPICKVAL(PrimaryDepartment__c, "Surgery"),
ISPICKVAL(Division__c, ""),
if(ISPICKVAL(PrimaryDepartment__c, "Pediatrics"),
ISPICKVAL(Division__c, ""),false)))
)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this with dependent picklists/required attributes on page layout?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the most efficient way to check multiple picklist values is to use a `CASE` statement:

```
1 = CASE(
    MyPicklist__c,
    "Value A", 1,
    "Value B", 1,
    "Value C", 1,
    0
)
```

Now you simply have to fit this pattern into an `AND` clause where your other argument is the field being blank:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(OtherPicklist__c, ""),
    1 = CASE(...)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian!

This is what I came up with:

and(
ispickval(Division__c, ""),
1=case(
PrimaryDepartment__c,
"Medicine", 1,
"Surgery", 1,
"Pediatrics", 1,
0)
)

However, the Division field becomes required when I select any value from PrimaryDepartment. Where did I go wrong.

Comment: @KevinWollenberg Even when you select a value not included in your `CASE` statement? The fallback value is `0`, meaning that statement should be false, and hence the entire `AND` statement.

Comment: Silly mistake, I had the field marked as required on the page layout. The validation rule works as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: @KevinWollenberg If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score -2):

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(picklist_name__c, 'PickList Value'),
    ISBLANK(field1__c)
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this answer is what we call a _code dump_. Code dumps tend to be poor answers because they don't help people understand what the issue was, or why the fix works. They also tend to generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead" which makes it hard for other people with similar problems to follow. Generally speaking, the more explanation you can give, the better.